# MySQL Trigger - AFTER UPDATE - uses cached stale data

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

My system has two tables `products` and `prod_item` as below.

```
  CREATE TABLE `products` (
      `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `prod_desc` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
      `cat_type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
      `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `instock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;



CREATE TABLE `prod_item` (
  `prod_code` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplier` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `prod_condition` enum('New','Old','Damaged','Lost') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'New',
  `availability` enum('available','no stock','pick-up','delivery','reserved') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I have the below `TRIGGER` defined on `products` table on update of a product.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `upd_cat_code` 
    AFTER UPDATE ON `products` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
            DECLARE vcOldCode VARCHAR(50);
            DECLARE vcNewCode VARCHAR(50);
            IF ((! (NEW.cat_type <=> OLD.cat_type)) )
            THEN
                SELECT LEFT(prod_code, LENGTH(prod_code) - 4) INTO vcOldCode FROM prod_item WHERE prod_id =  NEW.prod_id LIMIT 1;
                  
                SELECT CONCAT(cat_type_code, "-", MAX(item_num) + 1, "-")
                    INTO vcNewCode
                FROM 
                    (SELECT cat_type, cat_type_code FROM prod_cat WHERE cat_type = NEW.cat_type) codes 
                LEFT JOIN   (
                    SELECT
                        p.prod_id, prod_code, 
                        CAST(SUBSTR(prod_code, 15, 4) AS UNSIGNED) AS item_num,
                        p.cat_type                                                                             ,
                    FROM  products p, prod_item pi
                    WHERE p.prod_id = pi.prod_id
                ) prod
                    ON codes.cat_type  = prod.cat_type;   
                
                UPDATE
                    prod_item
                    SET prod_code = REPLACE(prod_code, vcOldCode, vcNewCode)
                WHERE prod_id = NEW.prod_id;
            END IF;
        END
```

When I do an update on category (`cat_type`) in `products` table, the trigger gets fired as expected and the `prod_code` of `prod_item` table gets updated as expected. However when the same product row in `products` table gets updated again, the trigger gets fired, but `MAX` on item_num returns the value that was generated in the previous run of the trigger (or previous update). Essentially cached value is being picked in subsequent updates. Please see the scenario below for better understanding.

Sample rows from products table.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   prod_id   |   prod_desc   |   cat_type   |   stock   |   instock   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1      | fountain pen  |  ST_W_01     |   3209    |     1       |
|      2      | art pencils   |  ST_W_02     |     92    |     1       |
|      3      | rucksack      |  BG_C_01     |    455    |     1       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If the `cat_type` is changed, the trigger is fired to update the `prod_code` in `prod_item` table. `prod_code` contains a serial number within the category which is derived as given in the trigger query. It's incremented for each product added in a category. On category change, product moves from one category and get added to another category. However when the update happens one after another for the same product for correction due to wrong code assigned in the first attempt, the serial number is fetched for OLD category and not for the NEW. So for example, a `cat_type` "ST_W_01" has max serial number of 912, "ST_W_02" has a max serial number of 1405 and "BG_C_01" has a max serial number of 312. When I change from "ST_W_01" to "ST_W_02", the serial number for `prod_code` becomes 1406 as expected. When I change it again from "ST_W_02 to "BG_C_01", the serial number becomes 1407 instead of 313 as it picks the previous "ST_W_02" cat_type's serial and increments. Can this forum help me to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT LEFT(prod_code, 15, 4) INTO vcOldCode FROM prod_item WHERE prod_id =  NEW.prod_id LIMIT 1;` - the result of  LIMIT without ORDER BY is a random value.

Comment: Agreed with @Serg. You must add ORDER BY for to receive definite row in the query, now the query returns one indefinite row from all possible/matched. Moreover, the ORDER BY expression must provide rows uniqueness - if not then the output won't be deterministic again.

Comment: LEFT(prod_code, 15, 4)  is not valid LEFT syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Comment: @Salmon, thanks for pointing. For testing made some edits and pasted the same here. Now edited to correctly represent the logic.

Comment: @Serg, the result of the query will be product codes that differ only by last two characters which is not relevant to generate them. All values returned will be like XX-XX-XXX-XX-nnn-Ynn. Up until Y, all characters will be same for all rows returned as its getting filtered by prod_id, having a one to many relationship with prod_code. Hence for me any one of them is fine.

Comment: You are thinking about this the wrong way. Mysql treats every row in a multi row insert as if it was a single row insert so the 'previious' inserts are neither 'stale' or 'cached'.

Comment: @Salmon, this is an UPDATE trigger and not INSERT. Having said that, I may be wrong, but not able to understand what is causing this issue. If a value gets incremented from the past value of a row instead of current, my only suspect is cache. Is there anyway I can do an RCA for this and get this fixed?